Application.getResources() is null or {0} is not a valid data source
Previously myApp ran on Payara 5-2022.5 Community Edition with Jakarta EE8, java 8, and Hibernate 5.6.15 with multi-tenancy. And no any error when starting from Netbeans 22.
I converted myApp from javax to jakarta namespaces. Running on Jakarta EE10, when starting application from Netbeans, sometimes shows error(type 1 or 2) at the 1st time on Netbeans console (below). When had error, I just clicked to run again. myApp could start and no error message. Not sure which part is not completed or came from configuration.
The new environment is java 17.0.11, Payara 2024.7(Community), Hibernate 6.5.2, Hibernate Search 7.1.1 and other.
Error type 1:
INFO:   No deployment transformer implementation found.
INFO:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: myAppPU]
INFO:   HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
INFO:   [DEBUG] 10:39:50.828 | [RunLevelControllerThread-1721273928943] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider | injectService for DatabaseMultiTenantProvider

INFO:   [DEBUG] 10:39:50.896 | [RunLevelControllerThread-1721273928943] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider | datasouce casting result: org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource@453b2311

INFO:   [DEBUG] 10:39:50.897 | [RunLevelControllerThread-1721273928943] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider | can cast to DataSource

INFO:   HHH000025: Second-level cache region factory [org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory]
INFO:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: myAppPU]
INFO:   HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.5.2.Final
INFO:   [DEBUG] 10:39:54.237 | [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider | injectService for DatabaseMultiTenantProvider

INFO:   [DEBUG] 10:39:54.276 | [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider | datasouce casting result: com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.DataSource40@50f2da7c

INFO:   [DEBUG] 10:39:54.277 | [admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(2)] | DatabaseMultiTenantProvider | can cast to DataSource

INFO:   HHH000025: Second-level cache region factory [org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory]
WARN:   HHH90000029: The [hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization] configuration is deprecated and will be removed. Set the value to [true] to get rid of this warning
WARN:   HHH90000029: The [hibernate.enhancer.enableDirtyTracking] configuration is deprecated and will be removed. Set the value to [true] to get rid of this warning
INFO:   HHH000490: Using JTA platform [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform]
WARNING:   RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Cannot invoke "com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.Application.getResources()" because "application" is null]
WARN:   HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot throw exception because the return value of "java.util.function.BiFunction.apply(Object, Object)" is null
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doTheWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.lambda$delegateWork$3(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInSuspendedTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.getJdbcEnvironmentUsingJdbcMetadata(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:290)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1431)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1502)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:433)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:265)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    Suppressed: jakarta.transaction.InvalidTransactionException: Invalid transaction passed to resume() call.
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.resume(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:1129)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionManagerHelper.resume(TransactionManagerHelper.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaIsolationDelegate.doInSuspendedTransaction(JtaIsolationDelegate.java:130)
        ... 39 more

WARN:   HHH90000025: MariaDBDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
INFO:   HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
WARN:   HHH90000029: The [hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization] configuration is deprecated and will be removed. Set the value to [true] to get rid of this warning

Error type 2:
INFO:   Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
INFO:   Created virtual server server
INFO:   Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO:   Virtual server server loaded default web module 
INFO:   No deployment transformer implementation found.
SEVERE:   {0} is not a valid data source. If you are using variable replacement thenensure that is available on the DAS.
SEVERE:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
SEVERE:   Exception while preparing the app
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/myAppDS__pm), (applicationName=myApp2) }
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:598)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:522)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:150)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:571)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:1255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:433)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:265)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:303)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:351)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:281)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:65)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2103)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:67)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1213)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1144)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/myAppDS__pm), (applicationName=myApp2) }
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:142)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:594)
    ... 28 more

WARNING:   The web application [unknown] registered the JDBC driver [org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
SEVERE:   Application deployment failed: Exception while preparing the app
INFO:   Skipping registration of inhabitant for service reference [org.osgi.service.metatype.MetaTypeProvider] as the service object could not be obtained.
INFO:   JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:8686/jmxrmi
INFO:   No deployment transformer implementation found.
INFO:   Loading application __admingui done in 2,371 ms
INFO:   Initializing Mojarra 3.0.2 for context ''
SEVERE:   Exception while deploying the app [myApp2]
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationInfo is not available for application [ myApp2 ]


I'm afraid this isn't a simple problem and it would require a reproducer to investigate what's wrong. I suggest that you raise an issue on the Payara issue tracker. Or you can also try deploying the app on GlassFish 7, if you have issues with that, you can raise them on GlassFish issue tracker.

Thanks. I tried with glassfish 7, not success. When deploying war file on Payara 6 2024.7 docker image either full or web profiles, works smoothly.

What kind of issues you had with GlassFish 7?

Errors when used Glassfish 7.0.16:
(1). ][delegate=true, context=myApp-1, status=RUNNING, antiJARLocking=false, securityManager=false, ..]
org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Could not instantiate named strategy class [com.xx.DatabaseTenantResolver]
(2). Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ConfigProviderResolver implementation found!
at org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigProviderResolver.loadSpi(ConfigProviderResolver.java:138)...
(3). Other

Do you use MicroProfile config in your DatabaseTenantResolver class? Do you have Hibernate in your WAR file or installed in domain lib folder? I think I know what's happening. I'm working on improvements in MicroProfile config in GlassFish. Currently, GlassFish only supports MicroProfile Config for classes loaded from the WAR. If MP Config is used outside of a deployed WAR, it gives the "No ConfigProviderResolver implementation found" exception.

Yes, you're right. I didn't include any Hibernate 6 lib to a domain lib folder and also used MP in DatabaseRenantResolver class. I'll test. Let you know later by adding Hibernate classes to lib folder.

Putting Hibernate to lib directory won't help. What would help if you moved the DatabaseTenantResolver class from the lib directory into the app, if possible.

I moved DatabaseTenantResolver.class to the root of application(../myApp/Database...class). It didn't work.
